# Names of children's games

Tags: traducción

There are many children's games that are played throughout many parts of the world. Do the following games exist in Spanish-speaking countries, and, if so, what are they called? (I found many of these on the [Wikipedia list of children's games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_traditional_children%27s_games))

- Arm wrestling
- Cops and robbers
- Dodge ball
- Duck, duck, goose
- Four square
- Hide-and-seek
- Hopscotch
- Jacks
- Jump rope
- Kickball
- Leapfrog
- Musical chairs
- Marbles
- Red light, green light
- Red rover
- Rock, paper, scissors
- Simon says
- Tag
- Thumb war
- Tic-Tac-Toe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid a lot of the names for this games are very local, I'm from Mallorca (Spain) and that's how I call them:

- Arm wrestling: Hacer un pulso/pulso
- Cops and robers: Policias y ladrones (a variant of Tag when a "police" catch you you turn into one so every time there's more people doing the catching)
- Dodge ball:Mato
- Duck, duck, goose: I played but I can't rememeber the name in spanish (in catalan we called it "comprau peix"/buy some fish as the first sentence of the song)
- Four square: Cuatro esquinas (not very popular around here)
- Hide-and-seek: Escondite
- Hopscotch: Piso
- Jacks:I think we played a variation called "cinco piedrecitas" but we play with little stones and no ball.
- Jump rope: Saltar a la comba.
- Kickball: I don't think that's played around here.
- Leapfrog: Piola
- Musical chairs: Las sillitas or El juego de las sillas
- Marbles: Canicas
- Red light, green light: Patito inglés. The "curator" has to say "un, dos, tres, patito inglés" as fast or slow as they want and during that time the others players can move.
- Red rover: I remember the game but I can't remember the name
- Rock, paper, scissors: piedra, papel, tijera.
- Simon says:Simón dice
- Tag: Pilla-pilla
- Thumb war: Pulso de pulgares/Pulso chino
- Tic-Tac-Toe: Tres en raya.

Comment: The names may vary, in Perú Dodge ball is also know as "Mata gente", thumb war as "Gallito", cops and robers as "poliladro"

Comment: tic-tac-toe as "michi"

Answer (score 4):

As Laura said, names for children's games tend to be very localized. Here is how they are called in and around Buenos Aires.

- Arm wrestling

  - **pulseada**
- Cops and robbers

  - **poliladron**
- Dodge ball

  - the variant Wikipedia calls *[prisonball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisonball)* is called **quemado** or **delegado**
- Duck, duck, goose

  - the variant called *[rag tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck,_duck,_goose#Rag_Tag_.2F_I_Wrote_a_Letter_to_My_Mother)* is called **huevo podrido**
- Four square

  - *never played it*
- Hide-and-seek

  - **escondida**
- Hopscotch

  - **rayuela**
- Jacks

  - a slightly different game is called **payana** or **tinenti**
- Jump rope

  - **saltar la soga**
- Kickball

  - *never played it*
- Leapfrog

  - **rango**
- Musical chairs

  - **juego de las sillas**
- Marbles

  - **bolitas**
- Red light, green light

  - **las estatuas**
- Red rover

  - *no idea, never played it*
- Rock, paper, scissors

  - **piedra, papel o tijera**
- Simon says

  - *can't remember, I'm pretty sure there wasn't any Simon involved*
- Tag

  - **mancha**
- Thumb war

  - **pulseada china**
- Tic-Tac-Toe

  - **ta-te-tí**

Comment: I've played Simon says simply as *Simón dice* but it could just be a direct translation. (I comment this answer as I'm from Buenos Aires too)

Comment: "Antón pirulero" has some slight resemblance to "Simon says".

Comment: Note: I rollbacked AlejoNext's and Javi's edits because they introduced terms foreign to the geographical area my answer is about.

Answer (score 2):

I have some of the missing ones:

- Duck Duck Goose

  - "De tin marin de dopin gue"
- Leapfrog

  - "Brincaranas"
- Musical Chairs

  - "El sin silla"
- Tag

  - "Tu las trais"
- Thumb war

  - "Enanos Luchadores"

Comment: How do you make bullets in the editor?

Comment: Asterisk at the beginning of a line, and then a space.

Comment: @Fortunato: Added the bullets.