# ¿Qué nombre recibe en otros países hispanoparlantes el juego conocido en España como "las tres en raya"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, diferencias-entre-palabras, juegos

Ayer estaba leyendo con mi hijo una de sus revistas y me encontré con la siguiente foto, que describe cómo hacer una versión de viaje de un popular juego conocido en España como "tres en raya":

[image]

La nota al pie de página, que explica que el juego tiene nombres distintos en distintos países de habla hispana, me hizo pensar en el stack.

> Este juego tiene un nombre diferente según el país: gato (México), michi (Perú), cero y cruz (República Dominicana), ta-te-tí (Argentina y Uruguay), la vieja (Venezuela), totito (Guatemala),
>   equis cero (Salvador y Nicaragua) y tres en raya (España).

En una [pregunta relacionada anterior](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1260/5481) se mencionaba ta-te-tí como nombre del juego, pero queda claro que este juego tiene nombres distintos en cada país. Algunos países de habla hispana no aparecen en la lista, por lo que pensé que sería interesante usar el stack tanto para validar la afirmación que se puede ver en la foto como para completar la lista.

Así pues, cómo se le llama a este juego en cada uno de vuestros países?

Comment: Yo diría "el tres en raya", no "las tres en raya".

Answer (score 4):

- Argentina: ta-te-tí
- Chile: gato
- Colombia: triqui
- Costa Rica
- Cuba
- Ecuador: triqui
- El Salvador: equis cero
- España: tres en raya
- Filipinas
- Guatemala: totito
- Guinea Ecuatorial
- Honduras
- México: gato
- Nicaragua: equis cero
- Panamá
- Paraguay
- Perú: michi
- Puerto Rico
- República Dominicana: cero y cruz
- Sáhara Occidental
- Uruguay: ta-te-ti
- Venezuela: la vieja